# Where can I develop on ARM NPU?

Tags: fpga, arm, microprocessor

Arm boasts NPU's that have been designed for vision inference:
https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/processors/machine-learning/arm-ethos-n

However I cannot find where to purchase/develop NPUs (i.e. using a development board).

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: ARM is selling IPs, not physical processors.

Comment: I see thank you!

Comment: Also these seem to be very new, so there are not many actual chips around having it

Comment: So does that mean for a given type of Microprocessor there are different chips. For example, Arm Cortex M7 processors maybe designed differently for different companies.

Comment: Sure. STMicro's STM32F7 is Cortex-M7 -based. NXP's MX RT1024 is Cortex-M7 based. But they are quite different if you look at them closely. You can think of ARM core as a CPU which cannot do much by itself, while the vendors build different peripherals around it to create a microcontroller or a SOC

Comment: That make sense, although just to be clear would the Cortex-M7 Microprocessor architecture be identical in both NXP and STM32 or other devices that say "Cortex - M7"?

Comment: Yes, the microarchitecture is the same in a sense that you can use the same compiler and the binary code is compatible as long as it does not touch the peripherals.

Answer (score 0):

The ARM Ethos U55 and Ethos U65 designs were announced in 2020.
But as of mid 2023, they are not yet generally available in chips and boards.

Some candidates that might be available in 2023 are:

- Alif E1/E2. Cortex-M55 microcontroller with Ethos U55 microNPU
- Alif E5/E7. SoC based on Cortex A32, with Cortex M55 + Ethos U55 microcontroller
- NPX iMX.93. SoC based on Cortex A55, with Cortex M33 + Ethos U65

Apart from that, it looks like we will have to wait until 2024 (or longer), to get chips with these ML accelerators.